# C# Numeric type casting between a generic and Built-in numeric type

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I arrived at this solution searching  to convert a numeric type to a generic type, but the solution became an extensive switch case.
Making it difficult to maintain and every "function" that works with mathematical and comparative operations, I need to replicate this...

Is there any way to reduce, simplify this conversion? Considering also whether the numerical data type accepts negative values ​​or not?

The goal is for this class to work only with the built-in numerical types.

```
public class Foo<TYPE>
{
    private static TYPE[] tuple = new TYPE[3]

    public DoSomething()
    {
       switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(TYPE)))
        {
            // Built-in Byte type.
            case TypeCode.Byte:
                tuple[0] = (TYPE)(object)(byte)0;
                tuple[1] = (TYPE)(object)(byte)0;
                tuple[2] = (TYPE)(object)(byte)0;
                break;

            // Built-in Signed Byte type.
            case TypeCode.SByte:
                tuple[0] = (TYPE)(object)(sbyte)0;
                tuple[1] = (TYPE)(object)(sbyte)0;
                tuple[2] = (TYPE)(object)(sbyte)0;
                break;

            // Built-in Short Integer type.
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                tuple[0] = (TYPE)(object)(short)0;
                tuple[1] = (TYPE)(object)(short)0;
                tuple[2] = (TYPE)(object)(short)0;
                break;

            // Built-in Unsigned Short Integer type.
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                tuple[0] = (TYPE)(object)(ushort)0;
                tuple[1] = (TYPE)(object)(ushort)0;
                tuple[2] = (TYPE)(object)(ushort)0;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("The generic type is not a built-in numeric type.");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one of the cases that makes me pine for C++ templates. :( This might be a decent candidate for emitting a few implementations at runtime.

Comment: No, there is nothing in C# that allows you to detect if a type is a numeric type.  The best you can do is detect value types.  That said, it is unclear to me exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  If you can tell us HOW you intend to consume the information it might be easier to give you a more useful suggestion.

Comment: How do you use `tuple`? It looks like you just want a generic `Zero` interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert an arbitrary value into TYPE you could use

```
tuple[0] = Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TYPE));
```

ChangeType has already the mappings between all primitive numeric types to convert between each other.

If it's just about assigning the default values (i.e. 0 for numeric types) you can use

```
tuple[0] = default(TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If type is a numeric build-in type you could use [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword to get a 0 (zero) of your type:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
    tuple[i] = default(TYPE);
```